# How to get rid of hairline from overlapping svg shapes

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am using d3 and SVG to draw a rectangle. I then draw a different rectangle that is smaller and a different color inside the first rectangle. When I change the smaller rectangle to the same color as the bigger one you can see a white outline of where the smaller rectangle was. What is the bet way to fix this so that the smaller one just blends into the bigger one?

Comment: Are you setting both the `fill` and the `stroke` to the same colour? It sounds like you are just setting the `fill`, not the `stroke`.

Comment: Also, please share your code for drawing the two rectangles? I cannot reproduce this myself easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your smaller inside rectangle has no `stroke` colour, then it should not be visible.

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">

  <rect x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160" fill="red"/>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>

  <rect x="220" y="20" width="160" height="160" fill="red"/>
  <rect x="250" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```